# Celery with Amazon SQS and S3 events

Tags: amazon-s3, celery, amazon-sqs

I would like to use Celery to consume S3 events as delivered by Amazon on SQS. However, the [S3 message format](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-event-notification/) does not match [what Celery expects](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html).

How can I consume these messages with minimal hackiness? Should I write a custom serializer? Should I give up and make a custom bridge using boto or boto3?

As a sidenote, I also want to connect Celery to a different broker (RabbitMQ) for the rest of the application messaging, if that matters.

Comment: The celery message format you link to is used internally by celery to communicate to workers which task to run, and which arguments to pass to it. The S3 message format you link to is to let you know about events affecting S3 objects. It makes no sense to talk about linking them together directly - it's like asking if you can connect an electrical wire to a water pipe in order to make an electric shower. You need some machinery in the middle to do some processing. What are you trying to achieve here? Make a system that will do some work (using celery workers) when notified of S3 events?

Comment: @scytale exactly. Fool's errand?

Comment: nope. reasonable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my specific use case, it turned out to be easiest to create a bridge worker that polls SQS and gives tasks to Celery with the default broker.

Not hard to do (although boto and SQS could use more documentation), and Celery is not well suited for connecting to two different brokers at once, so it feels like the best way to do it.

Answer (score 7):

You're going to need to create a service that listens to the S3 notifications and then runs the appropriate celery task.

You have a variety of options - the S3 notifications go out via SQS, SNS or AWS Lambda.

In fact the simplest option may be to not use Celery at all and simply write some code to run in AWS Lambda. I haven't used this service (Lambda is relatively new) but it looks like it would mean you don't have to e.g. run a monitoring service or celery workers.

Comment: Lambda was my first idea but then I got worried about having to handle the lifecycle of the code running in Lambda, and how to get authentication tokens in it for RabbitMQ.

Comment: Depends how long would that task run, right? Lambdas are limited to 15m if I remember well...

Answer (score 5):

Configure the AWS S3 event to invoke an AWS Lambda function. The function should be written to transform the S3 event message into the Celery message format, then publish the Celery message to SQS.  Celery would pick up the message from SQS.

S3 Event -> Lambda -> SQS -> Celery

Comment: I tried working on this structure, but the message format I used after referring [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/gE5irkuLVj0) gives `TypeError: dispatch() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)` with kombu. Have you implemented this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes. Here's a python implementation. https://gist.github.com/rhockenbury/74d176691a4d9e2a84f64cb314910fc6 Note that I've used the v1 task message protocol, but Kombu will detect this and parse it to v2. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html

Answer (score 1):

The notification message that Amazon S3 sends to publish an event is in the JSON format.
So you can configure your celery to serialize json.
Below is an extract from my config file (using django).

```
# AWS Credentials
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

# Celery
BROKER_URL = "sqs://%s:%s@" % (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = '<queue_name>'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None # Disabling the results backend

BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
    'region': 'us-west-2',
    'polling_interval': 20,
}
```